# Single developer process/practice/infrastructure recommendations

Tags: web

So, I'm about to embark on a fairly lengthy, time consuming project that could net me some good results/rewards - and I'd like to give everything the attention and focus it deserves. I will be the sole developer, and I'm experienced in that capacity (about 13 years in the industry). I've just never had to be responsible for EVERY choice so I'd like to throw this out there for some feedback. This is going to be a website.

Dev Tools on Win x64 workstation:

- VS2010
- SourceGear Client
- FileZilla
- UltraEdit
- SQL 2008 Mgmt Studio

I will have my own DB Server machine also, which will run SQL 2008 for both the web DB and will host the Soucegear repository DB.

I'd like to have an automated build process that includes

- pulling the latest code from the repository
- checking it against rules (ala FX Cop)
- compile the code
- running a series of tests against the new compilation (unit tests?)

Any suggestion on tools to do these tasks? Should I just write & execute scripts to do certain steps?

Backups! - I'd like the source code repository and web files, graphics, media, etc. for the site backed up regularly. I use Mozy for my own personal backups - is there something more suitable for this kind of backup? Windows Home Server or something like that perhaps?

Lastly - what am I not thinking of that needs to be on my radar? For example, I plan on using jQuery but only have limited experience with it - any good javascript tools besides VS2010? How to most web devs test their sites across the plethora of browsers available? Should I use minify-ing tools for the web content - which are best? I've built plenty of web sites & applications before - this is just my first real "commercial" venture and I'd like it be founded in solid practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, am a single developer and use much the same tools as you...

Couple of things...OK...it grew to more than a couple...

- I like to use UltraEdit sometimes for editing my javascript files...as it has some features that VS2008 lacks...not sure abt VS2010...mainly a function list to aid in navigation of the file.
- I also use [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com) to check the syntax of my javascript files...you can integrate it into UltraEdit...my choice...or VS...or both.
- I use subversion for source code control...Visual SVN for the server and Tortoise for the client...both free
- For backup I recently started using [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com)...you can point DropBox to the folder that holds your files and it will sync whenever DropBox starts (and it will keep the files synched on multiple machines...so if you have an offsite machine...you're covered if something happens at your main development site).
- If you'll be using LINQ at all...I'd recommend getting a copy of [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) It's free, but you can pay to get "intellisense"...the examples included are fantastic learning tools.
- When using jQuery...look for plug-ins that do what you're looking for...

Comment: So if I choose SVN over SourceGear - would you recommend having Visual SVN installed on the server with the database or on the workstation? (assuming it works on either). I've read some of the "Redbook" or whatever on SVN - I wouldn't mind using it instead of Vault - I don't have that much of a bias really.

Comment: @jamauss...I would install Visual SVN on the db server...then your source code (and any other supporting files you want to add) is basically saved in two places...it's kinda "belt and suspenders" but it's worth it and it's not much trouble at all to install...

Comment: For Linq - what's the word on what performs best in terms of ADO.NET Entity Framework or Linq - or from what I understand they can be combined...?

Comment: I've got projects using both...in the case of an EF project, you can(and will) absolutely still use Linq while using EF. I'm not sure abt performance, but I suspect that since MS has positioned EF as the preferred ORM, that it's the faster of the two.